# Dynamic loading of a webpage and div (ID's)

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic

Greetings once again...

I am trying to populate the different main templates for a webpage as well as dynamically call two separate divs ( I have the two divs loading, at least I thought I did... It works great in FireFox 5.0 but when I try the page in IE, Chrome, Safari or Opera the content disappears when clicked.)

Here is the jQ:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".swapJustInTimeLink").click(function(){

        document.getElementById("contentAll").innerHTML = "";

        $.ajax({
          url: "dynamicPages/progSpec_justInTime.html",
          cache: false,
          success: function(html){
            $("#contentAll").append(html);
          }
       });    
    });

    $(".swapJustInTimeLink").click(function(){

        document.getElementById("textWelcome").innerHTML = "";

        $.ajax({
          url: "dynamicPages/progSpec_links.html",
          cache: false,
          success: function(html){
            $("#textWelcome").append(html);
          }
       });    
    });
 });
```

Can someone explain when is going on here ?

My jQuery as well as AJAX skills are not refined enough at the current moment, thanks for any help.

Comment: Replace `document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = 'bar'` with `$('#foo').html('bar')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any reason you're not using [`$.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load)?

```
$(function ()
{
    $('.swapJustInTimeLink').click(function()
    {
        $('#contentAll').load('dynamicPages/progSpec_justInTime.html');
        $('#textWelcome').load('dynamicPages/progSpec_links.html');
    });
});
```

Comment: once again, it works great in FireFox but when used in other browsers it wipes out all the content to be dynamically loaded... I will however make use of the $.load()

it seems to fire quicker and produce smoother content.

Comment: @WebDev based on the code in your question I would **expect** the existing content to be removed. What else do you think `...innerHTML = ''` does?

Comment: it's removed, I know it blanks out the content. The code now works in FireFox, IE but not Chrome, Opera and with Safari it displays and dies.

I'm thinking that I might have an open loop. I appreciate your insight.

Comment: Once again thanks @Matt Ball I inadvertently forgot to fire up my WAMP SERVER again and was viewing from the www directly and not on Apache.

Comment: @Matt Ball I have chained about 60 links via the .load() command that I have since adapted and I am noticing a lagging issue. Can I use some sort of Break statement like JavaScript has ( possibly .end()? )to have it not skim the whole list looking for the triggers?